# Can't read from an array of pointers that point to arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

My problem should be fairly simple, but I can't seem to find a place where this is done in the exact manner I am doing it, or at least nowhere that I can adapt to this.

The idea here is to declare a char pointer, then using realloc, expand it into an array that I can then assign pointers that point to the starting character of an array.

From what I've read before, I should be able to just access it as if it were a two-dimensional array, but when I try the following code, I get an error: Invalid indirection in function main when I try to use printf.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *testArr;

unsigned char arr1[5] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
unsigned char arr2[7] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
unsigned char arr3[3] = {50, 150, 200};

int main(void){

realloc(testArr, sizeof(testArr) + sizeof(char *));
realloc(testArr, sizeof(testArr) + sizeof(char *));
testArr[0] = &arr1;
testArr[1] = &arr2;
testArr[2] = &arr3;

printf("%i", *testArr[0][3]);

getchar();

return 0;
}
```

I've tried a few things, including removing &'s from the assignment of the values into the pointer array, but I am honestly at a loss here. Perhaps someone with better C experience can help me here. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you call `realloc()` 3 times with the same arguments?

Comment: Just quick and dirty coding to see if it works. This isn't final code. In hindsight I have forgotten to remove one of them, as it should really only need it twice.

Comment: You should only need it once.

Comment: The idea in the future is to implement it into a loop. Either way, it's just somewhat inefficient programming that I do not believe affects the final product. Thanks for looking and helping btw.

Comment: But it's the same size each time, so you're not changing the size. What's the point of calling it more than once with the same size? Do you think `sizeof(testArr)` is going to change? It's the size of a pointer.

Comment: Nvm, that shouldn't be an issue. It's an array of pointers, so it should change?

Comment: Try changing `*testArr[0][3]` to `testArr[0][3]` in the `printf`

Comment: I had the same thought, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `malloc` or `realloc` should be the number of elements in the array *multiplied* by the size of each element, you shouldn't be adding. And you need to assign the result of the function to a variable.

```
testarr = realloc(testarr, 3 * sizeof(char*);
```

Since you want it to be an array of pointers, you need to declare it as:

```
char **testarr;
```

Comment: As it turns out that is the issue. I think it might have been due to me not using two asterisks. Looking that up it does appear that's needed. Many thanks.

Comment: I'd check this as the correct answer, but it's saying I need to wait a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You want to hold the `unsigned char*`-s. You will have to use `unsigned char**` in this setup.

```
unsigned char **testArr;
```

In `main()` the correct way to use `realloc` would be (this return value checking is needed).

```
char **t = realloc( testArr, sizeof(*t)*3);
if(!t) { perror("realloc"); exit(1);}
testArr = t;
```

Now you can simply do this (earlier what you did is assigning `char (*)[]` which even if you try in this case compiler would complain due to type mismatch)

```
textArr[0]= arr1;
```

Printing that would be

```
printf("%i", testArr[0][3]);
```